# How do I convert Mesh to MeshFilter in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I am making a Generation Game In unity, and I have custom meshes and I wanted a function to convert `Mesh` to `MeshFilters` in the fastest way cause this function will get a input of a `Array` of `Meshes` and the output will be a `Array` of `MeshFilters`.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty streight forward.

In general you don't simply "create" `MeshFilter`s. You rather attach them to a `GameObject`. There are bascially three ways to do so:

- use [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) in order to attach it to an existing object
- use [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) in order to create a clone instance of an existing prefab
- use the [constructor of `GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html) and pass the according type(s) in as parameters

And well then just assign your [`Mesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) to [`MeshFilter.sharedMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshFilter-sharedMesh.html) or [`MeshFilter.mesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshFilter-mesh.html) in this case where you assign the entire mesh it shouldn't really make a difference.

So you could e.g. simply do

```c#
// Needed for option B - see below
//[SerializeField] private MeshFilter preparedPrefab;

public MeshFilter[] CreateObjects(Mesh[] meshes)
{
    var amount = meshes.Length;
    var meshFilters = new MeshFilter[amount];

    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        // here you have multiple options

        // A - create a new empty GameObjects with the MeshFilter component
        meshFilters[i] = new GameObject("someName" /*, typeof(MeshRenderer), etc*/).AddComponent<MeshFilter>();

        // B - Rather already prepare a prefab/template which contains all the components you need
        // in particular you might also want a MeshRenderer in roder to see your objects
        // and e.g. MeshCollider in order to apply physics and raycasting to your objects
        //meshFilter[i] = Instantiate(prapredPrefab);

        meshFilter[i].sharedMesh = meshes[i];
    }

    return meshFilters;
}
```

---

Note that a `Mesh` itself has no information about any position, rotation, scale and child-parent relationships in your scene. For this you would need more information.